# getting NULL values from database

Tags: java, html, jsp, html-table

I am trying to display some data from my database with the following method but it only shows NULL values. I am not sure I have the right implementation of the method so if there's anything I should change when calling the select() method.
Thank you in advance for any help.

//SELECT method

```
public Res select(int id) {
            Res res = new Res();
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement preparedStm = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            try {
                connection = ConnectionConfiguration.getConnection();
                preparedStm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM res WHERE id = ?");
                preparedStm.setInt(1, id);
                resultSet = preparedStm.executeQuery();

                while(resultSet.next()) {

                    res.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    res.setDay(resultSet.getString("res"));
                    res.setNoRooms(resultSet.getString("rooms"));
                    res.setNoNights(resultSet.getString("nights"));
                    res.setRoomType(resultSet.getString("room_type"));
                    res.setUser_email(resultSet.getString("email"));

                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (resultSet != null) {
                    try {
                        resultSet.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
                if (preparedStm != null) {
                    try {
                        preparedStm.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return res;

        }
```

//JSP Page display

```
<h1 align="center"> Reservation </h1><br>
<% Reservation r = new Reservation(); 
   Res rb = new Res();
   r.select(rb.getId());
%>
<table border="1" width="50%" align="center">
<tr><th colspan="3">Date</th><th>Rooms</th><th>Nights</th><th>Room type</th><th>
Comments</th><th>Status</th></tr>
<tr><td><%= rb.getDay() %><td>
<%=rb.getRooms() %></td><td><%=rb.getNights() %></td><td><%=rb.getRoomType() %></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Make sure `resultSet` has valid values (by printing them or using a debugger).  How is `Res` defined ?

Comment: Res is another class (Bean class) which has the getters and setters of reservation

Comment: You are getting null because in jsp page when you declaring `Res rb = new Res()`  there is no value for `rb.getId()` .

Comment: how do I add the values then? could you instruct me

Comment: @Stephanie Do you want to get value dynamically for different user ?

Comment: Please post that servlet class and reservation page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it's worth mentioning that we don't use scriptlets anymore. Here's some information explaining why:

> The use of *scriptlets* (those `<% %>` things) in [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) is indeed
>   highly discouraged since the birth of *taglibs* (like [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)) and
>   [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) ([Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), those `${}` things) way back in
>   2001.
>
> The major disadvantages of *scriptlets* are:
>
> 1. **Reusability:** you can't reuse scriptlets.
> 2. **Replaceability:** you can't make scriptlets abstract.
> 3. **OO-ability:** you can't make use of inheritance/composition.
> 4. **Debuggability:** if scriptlet throws an exception halfway, all you get is a blank page.
> 5. **Testability:** scriptlets are not unit-testable.
> 6. **Maintainability:** per saldo more time is needed to maintain mingled/cluttered/duplicated code logic.
>
> <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle itself also recommends in the [JSP coding
>   conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to avoid use of *scriptlets* whenever the same
>   functionality is possible by (tag) classes. Here are several cites of
>   relevance:
>
> > From JSP 1.2 Specification, it is highly recommended that the JSP Standard Tag Library  (JSTL) be used in your web application to help
> >     **reduce the need for JSP scriptlets** in your pages. Pages that use JSTL are, in general, easier to read and maintain.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > Where possible, **avoid JSP scriptlets** whenever tag libraries provide equivalent functionality. This makes pages easier to read and
> >     maintain, helps to separate business logic from presentation logic,
> >     and will make your pages easier to evolve into JSP 2.0-style pages
> >     (JSP 2.0 Specification supports but deemphasizes the use of
> >     scriptlets).
> >
> > ...
> >
> > In the spirit of adopting the model-view-controller (MVC) design pattern to reduce coupling between the presentation tier from the
> >     business logic, **JSP scriptlets should not be used** for writing
> >     business logic. Rather, JSP scriptlets are used if necessary to
> >     transform data (also called "value objects") returned from processing
> >     the client's requests into a proper client-ready format. Even then,
> >     this would be better done with a front controller servlet or a custom
> >     tag.

Quote above taken from this wonderful answer:
[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Okay, now you understand why you shouldn't use scriptlets. So how else are we supposed to do what we want to do in our JSP pages? This is where JSTL and EL comes in. All you have to do in order to use JSTL in your project (if you're not using maven) is to download JSTL .jar file: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2 and include it in your `lib` folder (which is inside WEB-INF). If you don't have the folder create one and add the .jar file there. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) is a great resource showing all the things you can do with it.

Then in order to use it in your JSP just include the core library at the top of your JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Now to get back to your question. The problem lies here:

```
Reservation r = new Reservation(); 
   Res rb = new Res();
   r.select(rb.getId());
```

when you rb.getId() here and like that you are getting null because you're essentially doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE id = null
```

because you created a new object right before that line without setting the id (or anything else)

```
Res rb = new Res();
```

What you need to do is pass the object from your servlet and then you can use it. (without making a new object of res)

for example if you do this it should work:

```
   Reservation r = new Reservation(); 
   Res rb = new Res();
   rb.setId(1); //set the id 
   r.select(rb.getId());
```

But again, you don't want to do it like this. Because it involves scriptlets. And they suck. Since you now have jstl in your project, here's an example on how to do it with JSTL:

**ReservationStatus.jsp:**

```
<h1 align="center"> Reservation </h1><br>
<table border="1" width="50%" align="center">
<tr>
<th colspan="3">Date</th>
<th>Rooms</th>
<th>Nights</th>
<th>Room type</th>
<th>Comments</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>${Reservation.day}</td>
<td>${Reservation.month}</td>
<td>${Reservation.year}</td>
<td>${Reservation.noRooms}</td>
<td>${Reservation.noNights}</td>
<td>${Reservation.roomType}</td>
<td>${Reservation.comments}</td>
<td>${Reservation.status}</td>
</table>
```

Wayyy cleaner right? You actually don't need JSTL for this, cause you're only using EL here.

But again, if you just try and visit the jsp page directly, you will not see anything. You need the servlet to pass the data on to the jsp. What i would do to make this easier for you to test, is to change the doPost to a doGet in your RESERVATION servlet. This way, if type in the url that is mapped for this servlet in your browser: http://localhost:9191/ReservationServletUrl it will run the servlet and forward the details on to the jsp. (because doPost is not accessible via url directly like that, only doGet is)

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have trouble understanding anything!

Comment: Actually I do not want to use the setId(1); since I am supposed to get the id automatically from the getId(); method since I "do not know" the id of each user that will sign up and make a reservation. That's the problem I am having since I do not know how to get the Id. Maybe I can use session.setAttribute(); to pass the id from the servlet to the jsp page but I do now know how to save the id since I can only get it from the DB so should I run another query?

Comment: Ah i see. But you're not getting the id automatically, because you're not setting it anywhere after you create a new `Res` object. You could create a method that would get the last inserted row or get the id of the row that his belongs to and then pass it but this all seems like an over complication. But yes, could also set the id as a session variable, that certainly would work. If you're passing the data from the servlet to the jsp, you wouldn't need to do any of this.  It's difficult to give you a better solution because i can't see how you've set it up. Could help you in teamviewer

Comment: I'm a bit confused (or alarmed even lol), as to why you are creating a table each time you call the servlet?  `ud.createTable(); `

Comment: Not a problem at all. It's difficult to get a grasp of how it all connects without having something to reference it from. I felt the same way when i first started out down this path, totally understandable. So i'm happy to help out.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the url showing when you're on the page you expect to see the results on? And how exactly are you initiating it? Submitting a form? logging in?

Comment: I see, but you can't do it this way..  `out.println` defeats the whole purpose of having a jsp (to view the content on). And you need the jsp if you want to easily style the page, add functionality like buttons, interact with servlets.. i suppose you could do all that with a servlet but it's not practical - no one does it like that.

Comment: What is the url you see when you are on the page you expect to see the results on? (if i knew this i could tell you better how you can solve your issue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182644/discussion-between-jonathan-laliberte-and-stephanie).

Answer (score 0):

I changed it and put the code in a Servlet like below and now I display the data by using the email address since it makes everything easier. I did it as follows.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession s = request.getSession();
    ResBean res = new ResBean();
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStm = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String user_email = String.valueOf(s.getAttribute("uemail"));

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body><center><h1> Reservation Status</h1></center><br><h4 align=\"center\"> Rezervimi nga perdoruesi me email: " + user_email);
    out.println("<table border=\"1\" width=\"50%\" align=\"center\">");
    out.println("<tr><th colspan=\"3\">Data</th><th>Numri i dhomave</th><th>Numri i neteve</th>"
            + "<th>LLoji i dhomes</th><th>\r\n" + 
            "Kerkesa</th><th>Statusi</th></tr>");

    try {
        connection = ConnectionConfiguration.getConnection();
        preparedStm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE user_email = ?");
        preparedStm.setString(1, user_email);
        resultSet = preparedStm.executeQuery();

        while(resultSet.next()) {

            res.setDay(resultSet.getString("res_day"));
            res.setMonth(resultSet.getString("res_month"));
            res.setYear(resultSet.getString("res_year"));
            res.setNoRooms(resultSet.getString("no_rooms"));
            res.setNoNights(resultSet.getString("no_nights"));
            res.setRoomType(resultSet.getString("room_type"));
            res.setComments(resultSet.getString("add_comments"));
            res.setStatus(resultSet.getString("res_status"));
            res.setUser_email(resultSet.getString("user_email"));


            out.println("<tr><td>" + res.getDay() +"</td><td>"+ res.getMonth() + "</td><td>" + res.getYear() +"</td><td>"
                    + res.getNoRooms() + "</td><td>" + res.getNoNights() + "</td><td>" + res.getRoomType() + "</td><td>" +
                    res.getComments() + "</td><td>" + res.getStatus() + "</td></tr>");


        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        if (preparedStm != null) {
            try {
                preparedStm.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    out.println("</table></body></html>"); 

}
```

}

Comment: aww but then how are you going to get the user to interact with the page? don't you want to have buttons and things they can click on? printing the page out like that won't let you to do those things.